# How to hang curtains in a corner office with metal framing?

Tags: hanging, hardware, curtain-rail

This is in an office building with harsh sun in the summer. What hardware do you use to hang on metal framing?

[image]

Comment: You are showing commercial window frames. You can use a regular 1/8" High Speed Steel Drill to pilot a hole into the frame and use #8 metal screws to fasten. However, it looks like you will be running into problems at the outside corner because of the way the wall is designed. Your existing blinds are mounted between the verticals and they look quite close together at the corner. Hanging off the ceiling tiles is a very bad idea.

Comment: Is a window film or sun screen possible options? Might work out better than trying to hang curtains....

Comment: I misplaced my magnifying glass, but is there a reason a simple tension rod won't work here?